# select where column contains substring having brackets and quotes

Tags: mysql, select

how to select rows where column `story` contains `<p class='dg'>`
I tried all or nearly all variations with quotes and escapses
for example:

```
$sq = "select * from arts where story like '%<p class=\'dg\'>%' order by ind asc"         
$sq = "select * from arts where story like '%<p class=\"dg\">%' order by ind asc";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like PHP code. The backslash is special in PHP syntax as well as MySQL syntax. To get a literal backslash in the string, use a double backslash:

```
$sq = "select * from arts where story like '%<p class=\\'dg\\'>%' order by ind asc";
```

Alternative: In SQL, string literals allow a pair of quote characters to become like a single literal quote character. So you can do the following:

```
$sq = "select * from arts where story like '%<p class=''dg''>%' order by ind asc";
```